# Парсер не выводит русские буквы в TextView

Tags: java, android

Не могу вывести русские буквы в TextView через парсер. Использую такую комбинацию:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\'([^\'])\'$");`

пробовал вот так

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)=\'([^\'])\'$");`

тоже не помогло, выводит так текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
"/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я()]/u"
```

Comment: Пишет illegal escape charachter in string leteral